# conditional operator with a variable and an object

Tags: typescript

I have an object in typescript, where each key gives back an array of strings. I want to create a function that takes as an input a string, and either gives back the array with that key, or a predetermined array (this is just a simplified version of something). This works fine, but of course, there is a TS error since I'm using a string to index an object.  `Element implicitly has an 'any' ...` What would be the correct way to modify such a function?

I considered creating a third function where I use a type with `keyof typeof allowedValues`, and checking in my function if the string is valid, and if so, call that function, but seems unnecessary nesting, any help would be appreciated.

```
 const allowedValues = {
    val1: ["x","y"]
    val2: ["1","2"],
  };
  const getOptions = ( fieldName: string) => {
    const tmp = allowedValues.[fieldName] || ["k","i"]
    return tmp;

  };
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8XkAw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This works as desired! , I have only have one question, why the union with `unknown` for `_av`, all elements in `allowedValues` have a `string, string[]` pair, so there shouldn't be any case of unknown or am I missing something, thank you!

Comment: If you mean union with *`undefined`* (and not `unknown`) then I will explain in the answer I write.

Comment: While I'm working on the answer, could you please [edit] to remove the optional chaining `?.` from your code?  It's unnecessary and therefore distracting... `allowedValues?.[fieldName]` could only differ from `allowedValues[fieldName]` if *`allowedValues` were `undefined` or `null`*, and this is known to be impossible.  It has nothing to do with what happens if there's no property at the specified key.

Comment: Done! But now i have the feeling the name of the question might be not be total accurate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object types in TypeScript are *open* or *extendible* and not *sealed* or *exact* (support for which is requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)).  That means it's acceptable for a value of type `X` to have *more* properties than are declared in `X`.  This is a basic feature of [structural subtyping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#structural-type-system) and allows you to extend [`interface`s](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#interfaces) and [`class`es](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) by adding properties, so that interface and class hierarchies are also *type* hierarchies.

So the following code is acceptable:

```
type AllowedValues = {
  val1: string[],
  val2: string[]
}
const v = {
  val1: ["x", "y"],
  val2: ["1", "2"],
  val3: 123
};
const w: AllowedValues = v; // okay
```

There's no complaint about the assignment from `v` to `w`.  A value of the type `AllowedValues` must have `string[]` valued `val1` and `val2` properties, but it *might* have any other property at all.  You are not in general allowed to conclude that the *only* properties that exist are at keys `val1` and `val2`.

When we look at your `allowedValues` variable, we see that the compiler infers the same type as `AllowedValues` for it:

```
const allowedValues = {
  val1: ["x", "y"],
  val2: ["1", "2"],
};
/* const allowedValues: {
    val1: string[];
    val2: string[];
} */
```

And this means, fundamentally, the compiler has forgotten that `allowedValues` has *only* `val1` and `val2`.  It can't tell the difference between `allowedValues` and `w`, or indeed between `allowedValues` and any other variable of the same type.

---

Presumably your intent with

```
const getOptions = (fieldName: string) => {
  const tmp = allowedValues[fieldName] || ["k", "i"]
  //          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of 
  // type 'string' can't be used to index type '{val1: string[], val2: string[]}'.
  return tmp; 
};
```

is that it should always return a `string[]`.  But the compiler doesn't know this. It sees the same thing as

```
const getOptionsOops = (fieldName: string) => {
  const tmp = w[fieldName] || ["k", "i"]
  //          ~~~~~~~~~~~~
  // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of 
  // type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AllowedValues'.
  return tmp; // any
};
```

And if you called *that* like `getOptions("val3")` you'd get a `number` out instead of a `string[]`.  As far as the compiler knows, both `w[fieldName]` and `allowedValues[fieldName]` could be *anything whatsoever*.  And that's what the error is telling you.  Indexing into an object type with a key not known to exist  in that type does not produce `undefined`, but is inferred implicitly to be [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any).  Such indexing is likely to be a mistake and therefore you get a warning when using [the `--noImplicitAny` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#noImplicitAny) or [the `--strict` suite of compiler features](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#strict).

---

If you want to fix that, you'll need to tell the compiler that when you index into `allowedValues` with a `string`-valued key, you'll either get a `string[]` out, or you'll get `undefined`.  The way to do that is to give it a string [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) like

```
const allowedValues: {
  val1: string[],
  val2: string[]
  [k: string]: string[] | undefined // <-- string index signature
} = {
  val1: ["x", "y"],
  val2: ["1", "2"],
};

const getOptions = (fieldName: string) => {
  const tmp = allowedValues[fieldName] || ["k", "i"] // okay
  return tmp; // string[]
}
```

That works. If you don't want to mess with `allowedValues`'s definition, you can assign it to a temp variable of type `{[k: string]: string[] | undefined}` yourself:

```
const getOptions = (fieldName: string) => {
  const _av: {[k: string]: string[] | undefined} = allowedValues; // okay
  const tmp = _av[fieldName] || ["k", "i"] // okay
  return tmp; // string[]
};
```

And that also works and is self-contained inside `getOptions()`.  Hooray!  So we're all done here.  Except:

---

You might wonder why you're allowed to make the assignment from `allowedValues` to `_av`, given that `allowedValues` isn't known to be of type `{[k: string]: string[] | undefined}`.  After all, if it *were* known, then the compiler wouldn't have complained about `allowedValues[fieldName]` in the first place.

It turns out that this is due to a feature known as [implicit index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#implicit-index-signatures); you are intentionally allowed to assign one of these object literal types to something expecting an index signature, to make using index signatures less annoying.  It's technically unsafe to do this (and doing the analogous thing with *interface* types is expressly forbidden as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#15300](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15300)) but it's convenient.

Again, you might wonder, why not make it even *more* convenient by assuming that `allowedValues[fieldName]` produces `undefined` for unknown keys?  Well, there's a tradeoff between correctness and convenience, and here the TS team thinks correctness is more important.  So the best we can do here is to take the semi-convenient path of assigning `allowedValues` to an index-signature-having type and then indexing into that instead.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-ICxAglMmYAPpYDQky1jujZQRsyLorgbYQB2No9lmp7jIQH4ZNkuTzsMR6kEhNAXhB15ohiWJWKk6RZDkfrHK+YrvhxmGlsEQA)